# Ciclo Loop no para en nasm

Tags: ensamblador, nasm

Al intentar imprimir 10 veces el hola mundo se me cicla en nasm aqui el codigo 
alguna ayuda para saber que pasa ya que soy nuevo por aca

```
section . data

msg db "hola mundo",0xA,0xD

len equ $ - msg

section .text

global _start

_start:

mov ecx,1

etiqueta1:

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg
mov edx len
int 0x80

loop etiqueta1

mov eax,1
int 0x80
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenga en cuenta que en su código, el registro `ECX` se usa tanto como contador como para transferir un valor a una llamada al sistema. Debe guardar el valor de `ECX` hasta la salida de la cadena y devolverlo a `ECX` antes `loop`:

```
section .data

msg db "hola mundo",0xA,0xD
len equ $ - msg

counter dd 0

section .text

global _start

_start:

mov ecx,10

etiqueta1:

mov [counter], ecx

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx, msg
mov edx, len
int 0x80

mov ecx, [counter]

loop etiqueta1

mov eax,1
int 0x80
```